# How To Redirect Mobile Users to Mobile Theme

Tags: wordpress

Well I've many visitors who visits my wordpress blog from there mobile 
and also have visitors who visits from computers 
the average for both is 50-50

I want if someone visit from mobile then that user redirect to mobile theme else person redirect to computer theme

Is There any theme which supports both or any plugin or code which allow to activate 2 themes at a same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a few ideas here [Which WordPress Plugin Do You Use for Mobile Phone Compatibility?](http://www.webtechwise.com/which-wordpress-plugin-do-you-use-for-mobile-phone-compatibility/)

Answer (score 0):

A perfect plugin for you. That detects either a user is from mobile device or desktop.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/mdc-theme-switcher/